# Растянуть несколько div внутри другого по высоте

Tags: css, html

Есть блоки:

```html
<div class='div1' width="550px">
<div><img/></div>
<div><img/></div>
<div><img/></div>
<div><img/></div>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы все 4 или больше блоков равномерно растягивались по высоте, но не более 80px.
А изображения внутри блоков - по высоте div, в которых они
Так не работает:
.div1 {height: 550px; background: #ddd;}
.div1 div {height:80px; max-height: 80px; margin: 6px; display: block;}
.div1 div img {height: 100%;}

Comment: Как 4 блока в высоту 80 пиксель могут равномерно растянуться внутри блока высотой 550 пиксель? 4 х 80 = 320

Comment: 4 - это образно. Блоков будет в разных местах от 1 до 10. Если один - чтобы была его высота 80, а если их 10 - чтобы по 55

Comment: Подправил вопрос

Comment: Вы отметили решением неверный ответ. Высота блоков превышает 80 пиксель.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот набросал вариант с использованием `display: flex`

4 блока - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/d4vffdb8/

5 блоков - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/a75z7743/

и т.п

10 блоков - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/xcpuhfks/

вариант с изображением - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/30csoo65/

Comment: Ответ неверный! Условие с высотой блоков не соблюдено.